# Have to press same button twice to call function Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to call the function 'Checks' at the end of my button function, so that the 'Checks' function is able to check the value of labels in the app, and change the background colour, based off the value of the labels that were manipulated within the GoButton function. e.g. if the weather is 'Cloudy', then I'll display some rain clouds, and hide the sun, and hide the rain.  Now, when I press the button, the button works fine, but the Checks function is not called, I then have to press the same button a second time, to get it to call?

I have tried placing the self.Checks() line above the catch, and outside of it, but it makes no difference, I still have to press the GoButton twice to get it to have an affect, and change the background.

Button Function:

```
//Go Button in Main View Controller
@IBAction func GoButton(_ sender: Any) {
    //text IS EQUAL TO WHAT IS IN THE TEXT BOX
    let text: String = userValue.text!

    //API URL TO FETCH JSON DATA
    guard let APIUrl = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + text +  "&appid=***API***KEY***&units=Metric") else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: APIUrl) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        //JSON DECODER
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        do {
            let weatherData = try decoder.decode(MyWeather.self, from: data)

            if (self.MainLabel != nil)
            {
                if let gmain =  (weatherData.weather?.first?.main) { //using .first because Weather is stored in an array
                    print(gmain)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.MainLabel.text! = String (gmain)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error in fetching data for your location: \(error)")
        }
    }.resume()

    self.Checks()
}
```

Checks Function:

```
func Checks() {
    //For some reason, this function doesn't get called on the first time you press the button? <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    if (MainLabel.text! == "Rain") {
        rainClouds.isHidden = false
        rain.isHidden = false
        sun.isHidden = true
    } else if (MainLabel.text! == "Drizzle") {
        rainClouds.isHidden = false
        rain.isHidden = false
        sun.isHidden = true
    } else if (MainLabel.text! == "Clouds") {
        rainClouds.isHidden = false
        rain.isHidden = true
        sun.isHidden = true
    } else if (MainLabel.text! == "Cloudy") {
        rainClouds.isHidden = false
        rain.isHidden = true
        sun.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you call `self.Checks()` in the wrong place. You are calling it long before the data is loaded (do some research on asynchronous calls). Move it to inside the completion handler where you set the label's text.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.MainLabel.text! = String (gmain)

    self.Checks()
}
```

Unrelated but it is standard practice that function names, variable names, and enum cases start with lowercase letters. Class, struct, and enum names start with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

You have two places in your function that silently return when the guard conditions fail. I would tuck log statements in those blocks to see which one is causing it to exit prematurely the first time you call the function, and then you can work on why.

As a side note, I would also recommend using more descriptive function names, and ones that can't be confused with variable or object names.

Comment: This is incorrect. The call to `self.Checks()` is not affected at all by any of the code inside the completion handler.